# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes error when inserting

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I get this error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF ADDRESS_TYPE got
>   ADDRESS_TYPE

This is my CREATE script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE address_type AS OBJECT
(
    house_name VARCHAR2(20),
    street     VARCHAR2(20),
    city       VARCHAR2(20),
    postcode   VARCHAR2(9)
)
/

CREATE TABLE addresses OF address_type;

CREATE TABLE customers
(
    customer_id NUMBER(6),
    title       VARCHAR2(5),
    firstname   VARCHAR2(20),
    surname     VARCHAR2(20),
    telephone   VARCHAR2(12), --VARCHAR2 used as customer may use +44
    address     REF address_type SCOPE IS addresses
);
```

This is my `Insert` script:

```
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, title, firstname, surname, telephone, address)
VALUES (1, 'mr', 'ross', 'xd', '01234881632', 
        address_type('exdee', 'may road', 'lurvey', 'rs34 8dt'));
```

I have tried putting `REF address_type` in the insert table but that didn't work, it just asked for a comma. I have also tried removing the `REF` from the create table. I'm not sure what I have done wrong here, would appreciate some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent datatypes: expected REF got .. error when trying to insert data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007190/inconsistent-datatypes-expected-ref-got-error-when-trying-to-insert-data)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `REF` or `SCOPE IS address`. Just change your line to:

```
address     address_type
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91ed6/2)